# Process video using ffmpeg while recording with MediaRecorder in Android

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, android-ffmpeg

Currently, I am processing video after recording using MediaRecorder. Is there any way I can do same while recording. This will save some waiting time for users.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this Guy's answer using FFmpegFrameRecorder - [Get/modify frames while recording mp4 with MediaRecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280023/get-modify-frames-while-recording-mp4-with-mediarecorder). Basically you need to capture frames on 'onPreviewFrames ' method and process on the fly using ffmpeg.