# Adding watermark on video while recording

Tags: android, video, watermark

I am trying to add watermark on video at recording time only. But I am not getting any proper solution for it. I have tried [this](https://github.com/tcking/GiraffeCompressor) library to add watermark to a video which is already recorded. But this approach takes a long time to add watermark to pre-recorded video. So I changed my approach to adding watermark on video while recording only. Please tell me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Why don't you add a watermark as a frame layout on the main view?

Comment: Are you using android studio?

Comment: Yes I am using android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [ffmpeg library](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) `overlay` filter to achieve this. [Here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) is the documentation for the above solution.

Comment: I have used ffmpeg as well but it provides a way to add watermark to video file. I want to add a watermark while the video is getting recorded.

Comment: @bhagyawantbiradar Check this post, you might be able to apply this to individual frames using ffmpeg during recording, but seeing how slow ffmpeg is, this is not a very good solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280023/get-modify-frames-while-recording-mp4-with-mediarecorder